# Unable to deploy datalust/seq to Google Cloud Run

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, serilog, seq-logging

Please I have been trying to deploy Seq on google cloud run but every attempt failed with the error below.

`The user-provided container failed to start and listen on the port defined provided by the PORT=5341 environment variable.`

No matter what port I specified, the Cloud Run build always return the above error with the specified port number.

```
docker run --name seq -d --restart unless-stopped -e ACCEPT_EULA=Y -p 5341:8081 datalust/seq:latest
docker tag datalust/seq gcr.io/chisquares/seq
docker push gcr.io/chisquares/seq
gcloud run deploy --image gcr.io/chisquares/seq:latest --max-instances=3 --port 8081
```

Am I doing anything wrong?

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to access Seq on port 8081 then the `-p` port binding should be `-p 8081:80`: the first part is the public port, the second is the container port.

Seq's `datalust/seq` container listens for all HTTP traffic (API and ingestion) on 80, and for ingestion only on 5341.

You'll also need to select Cloud Run's [second generation execution environment](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/execution-environments) to enable the Linux features that Seq relies on.

Comment: Credit for this answer belongs to @liammclennan :-)

Comment: I tried with your suggestions but still got the same error as before.

`docker run --name seq -d --restart unless-stopped -e ACCEPT_EULA=Y -p 8081:80 datalust/seq:latest`

Comment: Edited to mention second generation EE.

Comment: Thank you @Nicholas Blumhardt. Changing the environment to second generation EE works.